# Are ECS Task Definitions supposed to be committed into version control?

Tags: amazon-web-services, version-control, amazon-ecs

I'm fairly new to AWS ECS and am unsure if you are supposed to commit into version control some things that AWS already hosts for you. Specifically, should task-definitions created on AWS be committed to GitHub? Or do we just use AWS ECS/ECR as the version control FOR ECS Task definitions?

Answer (score 0):

First ECS/ECR not used for version control like GithHub.

ECS is container management service where ECR is nothing but docker registry on AWS.

Task definition used to run docker container in ECS.You can create task definition on or after creating ECS cluster.You can create/modify task definition in many ways like console,aws cli, aws cloud formation,terraform etc. It depends on how you want to do this and how frequently you change task definition. yes, you can keep your task definition GitHub and create automated job to execute every time from there but there is no need to store task definition anywhere once your task running.

Answer (score -1):

ECR is Elastic container registry which is used to store the container images.

ECS Task definition A task definition is required to run Docker containers in Amazon ECS. Some of the parameters you can specify in a task definition & include: The Docker images to use with the containers in your & task.

You have to provide your ECR URI while creating task definition or it will look for the default docker hub registry for the container image.

Also, You can keep your task definition json on any version control system if you want to use them lateron.

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question.